# Does ASRock B85 PRO4 motherboard support SLI?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, sli

Does the ASRock B85 PRO4 motherboard support SLI?

It apparently has two slots for graphic cards. Is it possible to plug in two SLI nVidia graphic cards and connect them via SLI (and why)? I found 4 sources, 2 of them said yes, 2 of them said no.

Product page: http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/B85%20Pro4/
Manual: ftp://europe.asrock.com/manual/B85%20Pro4.pdf

My knowledge in this way isn't deep enough yet.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sourcing a few sites for my answer - puget systems has a [lovely overview on their blog](http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Z87-H87-H81-Q87-Q85-B85-What-is-the-difference-473/) on the difference between chipsets and that essentially explains that the Z series has SLI support since it can split up lanes from the CPU and the other models can't.

Annoyingly, while intel's page for the [b77 chipset *explicitly* says Supported Processor PCI Express Port Configurations: 1 x x16](http://ark.intel.com/products/75019/Intel-DH82B85-PCH) the [z77 specs do not mention this specification at all](http://ark.intel.com/products/64024/Intel-BD82Z77-PCH).

*However* there's a bit more to this. The board supports *crossfire* since crossfire is designed to work with dissimilar boards (see page 26 of your manual), which confirms what puget systems says about the chipset, as well as that you can have 1 x16 *not* 2 x8 as is typical for SLI.

TLDR: No, SLI is not an option for this specific chipset and board.